# CGAffineTransform tanslationX or translatedBy

Tags: swift, cgaffinetransform

I'm getting confused.

Using vision, I transform bottom-left coordinates to top-left by

`CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1).translatedBy(x:0, y: -1)`

however to rotate the camera view according to the orientation I
`CGAffineTransform(translationX: 1, y: 0), rotated(by: -CGFloat.pi / 2)`

why in the second case do we use CGAffineTransform(translationX... rather than CGAffineTransform(scaleX..

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: All the difference in the world. Scale scales (changes size). Translate translates (changes position).

Comment: So why to transform bottom-left coordinates to top left do we use scale? Shouldn't we use translation? This is from an Apple video

Comment: Because you're not moving, you're flipping. So you reverse the scale. It's like turning a ruler over.

Comment: Transformation matrixes are confusing, and require pretty deep study to understand. Buy a book on 3D graphics and read the section on transformation matrixes. Then use a sample app and **try** to combine translations, scales, flips, and rotations. When nothing works like you expected it to, go back and read the book again. Repeat that until you start to get it.

Comment: (One confusing thing is that transforms are not commutative. The order you apply them changes the outcome, and it requires careful thought to figure out the correct sequence to apply transforms to get a desired result, even after you understand how they work.)

Answer (score 3):

> So why to transform bottom-left coordinates to top left do we use scale

So your question really is: Why is

```
CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1).translatedBy(x:0, y: -1)
```

the way to flip?

Let's start with the `scale` part. Scaling the `y` coordinate system to `-1` is a multiplication: it reverses the scale so that up is down. That's the flip. (Scaling the `x` to `1` just means "leave it alone".)

The `translate` part is because transforms take place around the origin (the bottom left corner, originally). So when we flip by scaling, we flip ourselves right off the screen. In order to compensate for that, we slide back onto the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They have a completely different meaning from each other, as per Apple doc:

**.translatedBy**

> Returns an affine transformation matrix constructed by translating an
> existing affine transform.

**.scaledBy**

> Returns an affine transformation matrix constructed by scaling an
> existing affine transform.